# Enlistar mediante un arreglo los dias del mes PHP

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Buen día, quisiera pedirles su apoyo para crear un arreglo donde me devuelva solo los días que tiene un mes, estoy creando un EXCEL mediante la librería de PhpSpreadsheet, y estoy en la parte de Encabezados, sin embargo estoy atorado en la parte de crear algo similar a esto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En estos momentos, solo tengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo buscando, no logro mostrar los días del mes, como están en la primera imagen.

El código que utilizo, para los encabezados es este.

```html
# Encabezado
$encabezado = ["NÚM", "NOMBRE", "DIRECCION"];


$activeSheet->fromArray($encabezado, null, 'A10');
```

No se si alguien pueda apoyarme.

Comment: ¿Los días de qué mes y de qué año y de dónde tomarías ese dato?

Comment: El dato, seria del mes actual, la idea es que mediante un formulario donde vienen los meses del año actual, genere un excel haciendo una petición a MYSQL.

La idea es que solo genere el EXCEL con datos del mes seleccionado.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr esto con las clases `DateTime`, `DatePeriod` y `DateInterval`.

Se trata de crear dos objetos `DateTime` situados en la fecha actual, uno con el primer día del mes, otro con el último día. A partir de ahí creas un período y obtienes los días de ese período.

Dado que no existen días en español, crearemos un array a mano para obtener las letras de los días según ese array, usando `w`, que representa los días en un índice como los arrays, partiendo de `0` para el día Domingo, etc.

El código sería este: [**<kbd>`Ver Demo`</kbd>**](https://rextester.com/ZTX54071)

```
$encabezado = ["NÚM", "NOMBRE", "DIRECCION"];

/*
    Creamos dos fechas desde la fecha actual
    una situada en el primer día del mes
    y la otra en el último día
*/
$firstDate = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$lastDate = new DateTime('last day of this month');
/*
    Agregamos 1 día a la fecha del fin
    para que sea incluida en el período 
    en PHP 8+ puedes omitir esto,
    pasando a $datePeriod un 4º parámetro: DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE
*/    
$lastDate->modify('+1 day');
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod($firstDate, $dateInterval ,$lastDate);
/*
    Un array de caracteres, para asignarlos
    según el número del día de la semana,
    que obtendremos con "w", según el cual:
    0 = Domingo, 1 = Lunes, etc
*/
$daysChar=array('D','L','M','M','J','V','S');

/*
    Recorremos nuestro período
    y terminamos de llenar $encabezado
*/
foreach($datePeriod as $date){
    $encabezado [] = sprintf("%s%d",$daysChar[$date->format("w")],$date->format("j"));
}

/*
    Probamos el resultado
*/
var_dump($encabezado);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(33) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "NÚM"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "NOMBRE"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "DIRECCION"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "M1"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "M2"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "J3"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "V4"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "S5"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "D6"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "L7"
  [10]=>
  string(2) "M8"
  [11]=>
  string(2) "M9"
  [12]=>
  string(3) "J10"
  [13]=>
  string(3) "V11"
  [14]=>
  string(3) "S12"
  [15]=>
  string(3) "D13"
  [16]=>
  string(3) "L14"
  [17]=>
  string(3) "M15"
  [18]=>
  string(3) "M16"
  [19]=>
  string(3) "J17"
  [20]=>
  string(3) "V18"
  [21]=>
  string(3) "S19"
  [22]=>
  string(3) "D20"
  [23]=>
  string(3) "L21"
  [24]=>
  string(3) "M22"
  [25]=>
  string(3) "M23"
  [26]=>
  string(3) "J24"
  [27]=>
  string(3) "V25"
  [28]=>
  string(3) "S26"
  [29]=>
  string(3) "D27"
  [30]=>
  string(3) "L28"
  [31]=>
  string(3) "M29"
  [32]=>
  string(3) "M30"
}
```

Como ves, en `$encabezado`, tienes todo lo que necesitas.

### Post-Data

Si la fecha no debe ser tomada del sistema, sino de otra parte, será relativamente fácil, con `DateTime`, obtener el primer día del mes y el último día del mes de cualquier fecha dada.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias colega, la verdad me sirvió demasiado.